# Freeradius: session timeout for multi concurrent login user

Tags: session, concurrency, timeout, freeradius

I would like to set session timeout for an account, for example, 3 minutes. If there are two or more users using this account at the same time, they then share the timeout. How can I achieve this with freeradius? I tried sqlcounter module but all users have 3 minutes. I also tried rlm_counter, but after the user is logged out by session timeout, he can login again and has another 3 minutes.